Do i need the `languageOptions.globals` field in eslint flat config when using typescript-eslint?
Is it necessary to have languageOptions.globals in my eslint flat config when using the type-script-eslint plugin? Doesn't typescript eliminate the need for this field? Or should i keep this in my eslint. I just don't want to have unnecessary linting when typescript already does this job for me, unless eslint globals has more to it.

It most likely depends on the config file. So, please show us your config.
